# Existence of a TFA group which can be written as an extension in two different ways

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm looking for an example of an abelian, torsion-free group, say $E$, which can be written on the
one hand as a trivial extension of two other groups $G$ and $H$, necessarily abelian, and also as a non-trivial extension of the same groups (so $G$ and $H$ must be torsion free as well).
It seems to be that $E$ would have to be very large (certainly infinitely generated), but I'm not sure if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plethora of silly examples constructed from any non-split exact sequence of TFA groups $A \to^{i} B \to C$. The group $E$ would be a countable direct sum of copies of $A \oplus B \oplus C$, $G$ and $H$ would be isomorphic to $E$. There are two obvious monomorphisms $G \to E$, let's call them $f$ and $h$.

Split one, $f$, is a direct summand inclusion; just take "half" of $E$.
Non-split one, $h$, is $f \oplus i$.

Now you only need to find that non-split exact sequence. One may easily see that $Ext^1_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z)$ is nonzero (and quite naturally isomorphic to the group of rational adeles). Pick any nonzero element of that Ext group.

PS: It would be interesting to get an example where either $G$ or $H$ is indecomposable (or even both); I'm quite sure that such example exists, but it is probably pretty complicated.